# Send query results to printer

Tags: php, mysql

I want to send the output from my MYSQL query to a printer at the moment the output is on my screen. My query code is below.

```
<?php    
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die ("Could not connect to database");
$today = date("Y/m/d + 1");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `lafont` WHERE  weekending> '$newdate' and weekending < '$newdate1'  order by weekending";
$result = mysqli_query($cxn,$sql) or die ( "error1" );

$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: Is the printer connected to the server or the client? If it's on the client, you have to do it in Javascript, PHP runs on the server. Use `window.print()`.

Comment: Its on the client. , Don't know much Javascript

Comment: You don't really need to do anything, the user can just use the `File->Print` menu in their browser. You can use CSS media queries to change how the page is displayed when it's being printed.

Comment: Tried the simple code :<form>
<input type="button" value="Print this page" onClick="window.print()">
</form> but it does not work, JavaScript is enabled on my browser

Comment: There's no need for `<form>`, but that should work.